# Fixed position issue with 100% width

Tags: css

I am having the following error when using

```
.high-secuity {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #ff782f;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

[image]

the issue is that the orange panels goes outside the screen. How can I fix this?Don't want to use fixed widths as it should be responsive

Comment: set `left : 0 ; right : 0` without need to `margin-left` or `width : 100%`

Comment: Tried that, then it gets the full screen.

Comment: Sorry sorry I got your point .. you need the header to be fixed with the same width as a parent

Comment: try `position: sticky`?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site to check? I think there might just be some `margin`  or `padding` causing the issue

Comment: doesn't work. I have added left: 0, right: 0, width: 60% and margin: 0 auto. it works

Comment: @mohsinali1317 by setting `width` to `60%` it wouldn't help you in a long term .. it'll just work fine on your test screen but not on all screens .. try to find another solution

Comment: maybe just add a max-width to the banner ?

Answer (score 0):

with `width: inherit;` to the orange block my example is working

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px 15px;
}

.high-secuity {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: #ff782f;
  color: #fff;
  width: inherit;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Osloskolen</h1>
  <div class="high-secuity">Your message</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is my solution on codepen: https://codepen.io/salvatorerizzello/pen/YBEPzZ
I have also added the same left and right padding as the container;

Comment: Hi @mohsinali1317, just edited my answer so you can check the code working  ;)